# Prove that if a vector $v\in V$ is such that $f(v)=0$ for any linear function $f$ from $V$ to $W$ then $v=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, solution-verification

Let be $V$ and $W$ vector spaces. So I ask to prove that if $\vec v\in V$ is such that $f(\vec v)=0$ for any linear function $f$ from $V$ to $W$ then $\vec v$ is the zero vector. Clearly my condition is equivalent to claim that $\vec v\in\ker f$ for each $f\in\hom(V,W)$ but ufortunately I do not be able to argue anything from this. So could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's only true if $W$ is not the trivial vector space $\{0\}$.

If $v\ne 0$ then you can extend it to a basis $v_1=v,\,v_2,\,v_3,\,\dots\,$ of $V$.
Let $w\in W$ nonzero and define $f:V\to W$ on the basis by letting $f(v_1)=w$ and, say, $f(v_i)=0$ if $i>1$.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand completely what you wrote. Why from what you showed follows the statement? Excuse me: forgive my confusion.

Comment: A basis consists of multiple vectors. Any linearly independent set of vectors can be extended to a basis, in particular $\{v\}$ can if $v\ne 0$. A linear map can be defined arbitrarily on a basis. I prove the contrapositive of the statement: if $v\ne 0$ then there exists a linear map $f:V\to W$ such that $f(v)\ne 0$.

Comment: Oh, yes! Now I understand: if $\vec v\neq 0$ then there exist a linear map $f$ from $V$ to $W$ such that $f(\vec v)\neq 0$ and this in the case we consider is impossible!

Comment: Now all clear. Thanks to much for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $V$ and $W$ are finite dimensional:

Let $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{C}$ be ordered bases for $V$ and $W$ respectively, and let $x \mapsto [x]_{\mathcal{B}}$ and  $y \mapsto [y]_{\mathcal{C}}$ be the corresponding coordinate mappings. For every linear map $T:V \rightarrow W$ there exists a matrix $M_T$ such that for all $x \in V$

$$[T(x)]_{\mathcal{C}} = M_T [x]_{\mathcal{B}}, $$

and vice versa (i.e. each matrix like that defines a linear map). Our asssumption is that for each $M_T \in \mathbb{R}^{\dim W \times \dim V}$, we have

$$M_T [v]_{\mathcal{B}} = \mathbf{0},$$

which means that $[v]_{\mathcal{B}} = \mathbf{0} \implies v = \mathbb{0}_V$, where $\mathbf{0}$ is the zero vector in $\mathbb{R}^{\dim W}$ and $\mathbb{0}_V$ is the zero vector in $V$.